# 4D matrix multiplication

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I have been failing to find a good way to write the below for loops using numpy. The way it is written right now is of course very inefficient and is just unfeasible for my real data (shape 512*8*8*512) but I am just failing to effectively use the built in matrix multiplication functions.

```
import numpy as np
#Create pseudo weights, biases, input
weights = np.random.rand(10, 8, 8, 10)
biases = np.random.rand(10)
pseudo_input = np.random.rand(10, 8, 8)
output_loops = np.zeros((weights.shape[0],))

for n in range(10):
    output_loops[n] += biases[n]
    for x in range(8):
        for y in range(8):
            for f in range(10):
                output_loops[n] += weights[f, x, y, n] * pseudo_input[f,x,y]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply port the relevant iterators into the `einsum` string notation in [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
np.einsum('fxyn,fxy->n', weights, pseudo_input) + biases
```

We can also use [`np.tensordot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) -

```
np.tensordot(weights, pseudo_input, axes=((0,1,2),(0,1,2))) + biases
```

Using the trusty `np.dot` with some additional reshaping to bring the shapes to `2D` and `1D` -

```
pseudo_input.ravel().dot(weights.reshape(-1,weights.shape[-1])) + biases
```

Comment: This time you pipped me literally by one second.

Comment: Phew! What an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another, possibly slower, solution:

```
output_loops = (weights * pseudo_input[...,np.newaxis]).sum(axis=(0, 1, 2))
```